# Error converting data type varchar to bigint using union

Tags: sql

Query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) '-1' AS hrempid, 'All employees' AS fullname
FROM employee
UNION
SELECT fullname, hrempid
FROM employee AS employee1 
order by fullname
```

Error:
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the columns in the wrong order after the `union`. Here is corrected version:

```
SELECT   TOP (1) '-1' AS hrempid, 'All employees' AS fullname
FROM     employee
UNION
SELECT   hrempid, fullname
FROM     employee AS employee1 
ORDER BY fullname
```

And better yet, use something like this:

```
SELECT   CAST(-1 AS BIGINT) AS hrempid, 'All employees' AS fullname
UNION ALL
SELECT   hrempid, fullname
FROM     employee AS employee1 
ORDER BY fullname
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave the `'` around your `hrempid` and switch the columns. Try this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 'All employees' AS fullname, -1 AS hrempid
FROM employee
UNION
SELECT fullname, hrempid
FROM employee AS employee1 
order by fullname
```